# VBA in PowerPoint only working with a stop and F8 stepping through it, When running by itself it changes fill color for shape 1 but not shape 2

Tags: vba, powerpoint

This code is used to do a timing sequence and depends on each segment starting at the correct interval which is set by a variable based on user input. With stops put in and stepping through the code it works correctly with no errors. When executed without a stop the command button "RunCommand" stays depressed for 5 seconds and shape 1's forecolor changes but shape 2 does not change. I have drummed the code down to this for ease as this seams to be the part given me the issue. I'm stuck, if I just run the code it does not work, if I step through the code it works fine?????

```
Private Sub RunCommand_Click()

Dim EndTick As Date

EndTick = DateAdd("s", 5, Now())
    
Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

    With myDocument.Shapes("Arrow3rd2").Fill
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End With
    
    Do
        If Now() > EndTick Then
            With myDocument.Shapes("Arrow3rd1").Fill
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End With
        Else
            DoEvents
        End If
    Loop Until Now() >= EndTick
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value for `Application.now` will change most likely during the `DoEvents`. So your program flow is

Check if `now > EndTick`: If yes, change color of shape.
If this is not the case, give time to do something else (`DoEvents`)
--> During this, now will increase.
Check again `if now > EndTick`: If yes, leave the loop.

So the part where the color is changed is probably not hit.

Try to change the logic so that the `If` is only hit once (code is untested)

```
Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until Now() >= EndTick
With myDocument.Shapes("Arrow3rd1").Fill
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End With
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked like a charm.